# how to send CSV files to ActiveJob in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rails-activerecord, rails-activejob

I'm trying to send a CSV file to the ActiveJob from my controller, but when I do it I get the following:

```
csv_data = CSV.read(params[:file].path, headers: true)               
ImportJob.perform_later(csv_data)
```

ActiveJob::SerializationError:

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError: Unsupported argument type: 
ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
```

I know that the parameter pass does not support file type in ActiveJob, and the most that I have tried was to convert it into arrays but it does not work for me

Any help would be very grateful

Comment: It is strange that the error is said about `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` because a result of `CSV.read` is an Array of arrays.

Comment: You are right, check again and for some reason I had not put the path. Thanks for the help me

Comment: You shouldn't pass complex objets to active job because deserialization is tricky. You can save the file somewhere (usually a temp file) and you pass the path of the temp file to the active job instead of the actual in-memory file object. Then you can simply read the file since you have the file path.

Comment: Excuse me for replying late, I will try your method for good practice since as you say, it has been giving me trouble passing large objects

Thanks @arieljuod